# Ktor parsing a map, similar to GSON

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, ktor-client

Ktor's ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json is not able to handle the maps parser, compare to GSON parser.

i.e -
Let's suppose the API response is -
Example -1

```
{
 "Activityformdata": {
  "activitydata": [],
  "activitydata_new": []
 }
}
```

Example - 2

```
{
  "Activityformdata": {
  "activitydata": {
   "Existing asset": "no"
   },
  "activitydata_new": {
   "Existing asset#SingleLineText": "no"
   }
  }
}
```

And the respective obj is -

```
@Serializable
data class ActivityFormData(
    @SerialName("activitydata")
    var mActivityData: LinkedHashMap<String, String>? = null,
    
    @SerialName("activitydata_new")
    var mActivityDataNew: LinkedHashMap<String, String>? = null,
)
```

Ideally ktor, should be able to parse this, and if data is empty then it should keep the value as empty in respective object.

But it's throwing the error.
exception: io.ktor.serialization.JsonConvertException: Illegal input: Unexpected JSON token at offset 152701: Expected start of the object '{', but had ':' instead at path:

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: what's the actual JSON that gets received by your application? Because both examples you provided are not valid JSON strings